# Creating a logical statement using paste inside a dredge

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `dredge()` of a model that contains quadratic terms. I know that you have to use the `subset` option. I have defined the quadratic terms

```
quadraticTerms = c("lux.mean", "temp.mean")
cand.set <- dredge(model, subset=as.logical(paste("(!",quadraticTerms, "^2|", quadraticTerms,collapse=' & ', ')', sep="")), extra="R^2", REML= FALSE, m.max=10)
```

I created a the term in paste() but it is not working. The dredge does work when you have it all typed out without the paste, like so

```
cand.set <- dredge(model, subset=(!lux.mean^2|lux.mean) & (!temp.mean^2|temp.mean), extra="R^2", REML= FALSE, m.max=10)
```

If someone could please help me with the second line, it would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Where does the `dredge()` function come from (ie, what package)?

Comment: @MrFlick - I think it's from `MuMln`. At least that's what `findFn` returned

Comment: It is a function from MuMIn @MrFlick

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like

```
subs <- paste0("(!",quadraticTerms, "^2|", quadraticTerms,collapse=' & ', ')')
model.string <- 
 sprintf("dredge(model, subset=as.logical(%s), extra='R^2', REML=FALSE, m.max=10)",
 subs)
cands <- eval(parse(model.string))
```

Usually `eval(parse(...))` is a last resort -- it will tend to be fragile -- but I can't think offhand of a better way to do this.  Looking at the "Subsetting" section of `?dredge`, it seems it might be better to try to do this via a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if they allowed the matrix syntax of the `subset=` argument to be as flexible as the expression syntax but that doesn't seem to be the case. Normally there are friendly "standard evaluation" alternatives to sneaky non-standard evaulation parameters like that but for some reason the package authors decided not to include such a workaround.

Nevertheless, there is a formula syntax alternative. You can build a formula with

```
subsetform <- as.formula(paste0("~(!",quadraticTerms, "^2|", quadraticTerms, 
    collapse=' & ', ')'));     
dredge(model, subset=subsetform, extra='R^2', REML=FALSE, m.max=10)
```

which should do the same thing as the expression. I tested with

```
library(MuMIn)
data(Cement)

fm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = Cement)
dredge(fm1, subset=(!X1|X2) & (!X3|X4))

# same as...
subsetform <- as.formula("~(!X1|X2) & (!X3|X4)")
dredge(fm1, subset=subsetform)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe your quadratic terms are sth like `I(x^2)` not `x^2`. Second, it may be simpler to use `dc()` to do that.

Example. Assuming the model is:

```
fm <- lm(y ~ X1 + I(X1^2) + X2 + I(X2^2), Cement)

v <- c("X1", "X2")
```

one-liner with `parse`:

```
ssexpr <- parse(text = paste(sprintf("dc(%1$s, `I(%1$s^2)`)", v), collapse = " && "))
```

or, longer, but without `parse`:

```
vquadr <- sprintf("I(%s^2)", v)
for(i in seq_along(v)) {
    x <- call("dc", as.name(v[i]), as.name(vquadr[i]))
    ssexpr <- if(i == 1) x else call("&&", ssexpr, x)
}
```

`ssexpr` is the subset expression to use with `dredge`.