# Subset dredge with variable names, inside a data frame (MuMIn)

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, rowwise, mumin

I have fitted models, and run `dredge()` on them. I have created a `data frame` that stores variable names used in the model, and the `dredge` object themselves (inside a `list`). By using `rowwise()`, I was hoping to subset the `dredge` object using the variable names stored in a specific column, and keep the subset in a new column.

My problem is that I cannot make this rowwise behaviour to work.

I can subset the `dredge` object just fine if I don't try to call the strings stored in other columns, see reproducible example.

I've found related questions from [2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252019/dredge-in-mumin-r-keeps-models-with-higher-order-terms-without-their-respectiv), [2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167595/r-subsetting-in-dredge-mumin-only-include-interaction-with-b-if-also-an-in), and 2014 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494509/creating-a-logical-statement-using-paste-inside-a-dredge), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247263/subsetting-in-dredge-mumin-must-include-interaction-if-main-effects-are-pres)). On one hand, these questions use `subset` inside the `dredge` function, rather than `subset` on an already generated `dredge` object stored inside a data frame. I've tried using the solutions outlined there, with no success, probably also due to lack of experience with parsing, expressions etc.

```r
library(MuMIn)
#> Warning: package 'MuMIn' was built under R version 4.2.3
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.2.3


data(Cement)


fm <- lm(y ~ X1*X2 + X1*X3 + X4, Cement)


options(na.action = "na.fail")


d <- MuMIn::dredge(fm)
#> Fixed term is "(Intercept)"


d
#> Global model call: lm(formula = y ~ X1 * X2 + X1 * X3 + X4, data = Cement)
#> ---
#> Model selection table 
#>     (Int)     X1      X2       X3      X4    X1:X2     X1:X3 df  logLik  AICc
#> 4   52.58 1.4680  0.6623                                      4 -28.156  69.3
#> 12  71.65 1.4520  0.4161          -0.2365                     5 -26.933  72.4
#> 8   48.19 1.6960  0.6569  0.25000                             5 -26.952  72.5
#> 10 103.10 1.4400                  -0.6140                     4 -29.817  72.6
#> 14 111.70 1.0520         -0.41000 -0.6428                     5 -27.310  73.2
#> 20  53.71 1.2750  0.6358                  0.004197            5 -28.072  74.7
#> 15 203.60        -0.9234 -1.44800 -1.5570                     5 -29.734  78.0
#> 28  72.43 1.2870  0.3959          -0.2343 0.003577            6 -26.860  79.7
#> 24  49.05 1.5580  0.6387  0.24590         0.002914            6 -26.904  79.8
#> 16  62.41 1.5510  0.5102  0.10190 -0.1441                     6 -26.918  79.8
#> 40  48.17 1.6690  0.6522  0.25180                   0.007277  6 -26.933  79.9
#> 46 112.00 1.0680         -0.41490 -0.6462          -0.005210  6 -27.301  80.6
#> 13 131.30                -1.20000 -0.7246                     4 -35.372  83.7
#> 32  66.63 1.3570  0.4556  0.06354 -0.1767 0.003398            7 -26.854  90.1
#> 56  49.02 1.5320  0.6342  0.24770         0.002888  0.007116  7 -26.885  90.2
#> 48  60.19 1.5560  0.5298  0.12600 -0.1218           0.004666  7 -26.911  90.2
#> 7   72.07         0.7313 -1.00800                             4 -40.965  94.9
#> 9  117.60                         -0.7382                     3 -45.872 100.4
#> 3   57.42         0.7891                                      3 -46.035 100.7
#> 11  94.16         0.3109          -0.4569                     4 -45.761 104.5
#> 2   81.48 1.8690                                              3 -48.206 105.1
#> 64  64.80 1.3650  0.4722  0.08329 -0.1585 0.003335  0.003693  8 -26.850 105.7
#> 6   72.35 2.3120          0.49450                             4 -48.005 109.0
#> 38  64.05 0.9528          0.49550                   0.311600  5 -45.678 109.9
#> 5  110.20                -1.25600                             3 -50.980 110.6
#> 1   95.42                                                     2 -53.168 111.5
#>    delta weight
#> 4   0.00  0.539
#> 12  3.13  0.113
#> 8   3.16  0.111
#> 10  3.32  0.102
#> 14  3.88  0.078
#> 20  5.40  0.036
#> 15  8.73  0.007
#> 28 10.41  0.003
#> 24 10.49  0.003
#> 16 10.52  0.003
#> 40 10.55  0.003
#> 46 11.29  0.002
#> 13 14.43  0.000
#> 32 20.80  0.000
#> 56 20.86  0.000
#> 48 20.91  0.000
#> 7  25.62  0.000
#> 9  31.10  0.000
#> 3  31.42  0.000
#> 11 35.21  0.000
#> 2  35.77  0.000
#> 64 36.39  0.000
#> 6  39.70  0.000
#> 38 40.61  0.000
#> 5  41.31  0.000
#> 1  42.22  0.000
#> Models ranked by AICc(x)


data.frame(test = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dredge = list(d)) %>% 
  mutate(subset = list(subset(dredge, delta <= 6)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   test  dredge               subset             
#>   <chr> <list>               <list>             
#> 1 X1    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [6 × 12]>
#> 2 X2    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [6 × 12]>


data.frame(test = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dredge = list(d)) %>% 
  mutate(subset = list(subset(dredge, has("X1"))))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   test  dredge               subset              
#>   <chr> <list>               <list>              
#> 1 X1    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [18 × 12]>
#> 2 X2    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [18 × 12]>


data.frame(test = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dredge = list(d)) %>% 
  mutate(subset = list(subset(dredge, has(test))))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   test  dredge               subset              
#>   <chr> <list>               <list>              
#> 1 X1    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [26 × 12]>
#> 2 X2    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [26 × 12]>


data.frame(test = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dredge = list(d)) %>% 
  mutate(subset = list(subset(dredge, parse(text = sprintf("has(%s)", test)))))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `subset = list(subset(dredge, parse(text =
#>   sprintf("has(%s)", test))))`.
#> ℹ In row 1.
#> Caused by error in `xj[i]`:
#> ! invalid subscript type 'expression'
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─... %>% ...
#>   2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
#>   7. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   8. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>   9. ├─base::subset(dredge, parse(text = sprintf("has(%s)", test)))
#>  10. ├─MuMIn:::subset.model.selection(...)
#>  11. │ └─MuMIn:::`[.model.selection`(...)
#>  12. │   ├─MuMIn:::subset_model_selection(item(x, j, i, ...), origattrib <- attributes(x))
#>  13. │   └─MuMIn:::item(x, j, i, ...)
#>  14. │     └─base::`[.data.frame`(x, i, name, ...)
#>  15. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  16.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  17.     └─rlang::abort(message, class = error_class, parent = parent, call = error_call)


data.frame(test = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dredge = list(d)) %>% 
  mutate(subset = list(subset(dredge, eval(parse(text = sprintf("has(%s)", test))))))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `subset = list(subset(dredge, eval(parse(text =
#>   sprintf("has(%s)", test)))))`.
#> ℹ In row 1.
#> Caused by error in `has()`:
#> ! no se pudo encontrar la función "has"
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─... %>% ...
#>   2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
#>   7. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   8. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>   9. ├─base::subset(dredge, eval(parse(text = sprintf("has(%s)", test))))
#>  10. ├─MuMIn:::subset.model.selection(...)
#>  11. │ ├─MuMIn:::`[.model.selection`(...)
#>  12. │ │ ├─MuMIn:::subset_model_selection(item(x, j, i, ...), origattrib <- attributes(x))
#>  13. │ │ └─MuMIn:::item(x, j, i, ...)
#>  14. │ │   └─base::`[.data.frame`(x, i, name, ...)
#>  15. │ └─MuMIn:::subset_eval(substitute(subset), x, parent.frame())
#>  16. │   └─base::eval(...)
#>  17. │     └─base::eval(...)
#>  18. │       └─base::eval(parse(text = sprintf("has(%s)", test)))
#>  19. │         └─base::eval(parse(text = sprintf("has(%s)", test)))
#>  20. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  21.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  22.     └─rlang::abort(message, class = error_class, parent = parent, call = error_call)


data.frame(test = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dredge = list(d)) %>% 
  mutate(subset = list(subset(dredge, has(substitute(v, list(v = as.name("test")))))))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `subset = list(subset(dredge, has(substitute(v, list(v =
#>   as.name("test"))))))`.
#> ℹ In row 1.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! objeto 'substitute(v, list(v = as.name("test")))' no encontrado
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─... %>% ...
#>   2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., subset = list(subset(dredge, has(substitute(v, list(v = as.name("test")))))))
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
#>   7. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   8. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>   9. ├─base::subset(dredge, has(substitute(v, list(v = as.name("test")))))
#>  10. ├─MuMIn:::subset.model.selection(dredge, has(substitute(v, list(v = as.name("test")))))
#>  11. │ ├─MuMIn:::`[.model.selection`(...)
#>  12. │ │ ├─MuMIn:::subset_model_selection(item(x, j, i, ...), origattrib <- attributes(x))
#>  13. │ │ └─MuMIn:::item(x, j, i, ...)
#>  14. │ │   └─base::`[.data.frame`(x, i, name, ...)
#>  15. │ └─MuMIn:::subset_eval(substitute(subset), x, parent.frame())
#>  16. │   └─base::eval(...)
#>  17. │     └─base::eval(...)
#>  18. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  19.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  20.     └─rlang::abort(message, class = error_class, parent = parent, call = error_call)


sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
#> [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.utf8    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.2     purrr_1.0.1    
#>  [5] readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.4.0  
#>  [9] tidyverse_1.3.1 MuMIn_1.47.5   
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] tidyselect_1.2.0 xfun_0.40        haven_2.5.0      lattice_0.20-45 
#>  [5] colorspace_2.0-3 vctrs_0.6.3      generics_0.1.2   htmltools_0.5.6 
#>  [9] stats4_4.2.0     yaml_2.3.5       utf8_1.2.2       rlang_1.1.1     
#> [13] pillar_1.9.0     glue_1.6.2       withr_2.5.0      DBI_1.1.2       
#> [17] dbplyr_2.1.1     readxl_1.4.0     modelr_0.1.8     lifecycle_1.0.3 
#> [21] cellranger_1.1.0 munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.0     rvest_1.0.2     
#> [25] evaluate_0.15    knitr_1.39       tzdb_0.3.0       fastmap_1.1.0   
#> [29] fansi_1.0.3      highr_0.9        broom_0.8.0      backports_1.4.1 
#> [33] scales_1.2.1     jsonlite_1.8.0   fs_1.5.2         hms_1.1.1       
#> [37] digest_0.6.29    stringi_1.7.6    grid_4.2.0       cli_3.6.1       
#> [41] tools_4.2.0      magrittr_2.0.3   crayon_1.5.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
#> [45] ellipsis_0.3.2   Matrix_1.4-1     xml2_1.3.3       lubridate_1.8.0 
#> [49] reprex_2.0.2     assertthat_0.2.1 rmarkdown_2.14   httr_1.4.3      
#> [53] rstudioapi_0.13  R6_2.5.1         nlme_3.1-157     compiler_4.2.0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why the subset won't work inside `mutate()` the usual way.  I was able to get the desired result using `map()` inside the `mutate()` function.  The documentation for `subset` for the dredge object says that `has("X1")` is equivalent to `!is.na(X1)`, so I used the latter instead (`has()` still doesn't work in this context).

```r
library(MuMIn)
library(tidyverse)
data(Cement)
fm <- lm(y ~ X1*X2 + X1*X3 + X4, Cement)
options(na.action = "na.fail")
d <- MuMIn::dredge(fm)
#> Fixed term is "(Intercept)"

data.frame(test = c("X1", "X2")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(dredge = list(d)) %>% 
  mutate(subset = map(test, \(x)subset(d, !is.na(d[[x]]))))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   test  dredge               subset              
#>   <chr> <list>               <list>              
#> 1 X1    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [18 × 12]>
#> 2 X2    <mdl.slct [26 × 12]> <mdl.slct [16 × 12]>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your solution works, thank you! I realized that you could also do subsetting with filter(), as dredge is also class data.frame. I used get() inside filter() in order to use a variable name sotred in a data frame column (filter(get(column_storing_variable_name)).

Comment: @M.Riera also a great solution.